# PHP websocket realtime updates on multiple devices

Tags: php, websocket, zeromq, rpc, ratchet

I am trying to implement a very simple self-hosted (docker) pubsub client update system using websockets or SSE for my PHP application.

I would like that a specific javascript action on my website triggers a php server-side update (via ajax) which should then lead to an update to all subscribed devices for the particular channel/topic. The subscribed devices should use javascript listening to one channel each.

Do you know any simple PHP ws libraries which are capable of that? Can SSE be triggered in that way and also utilize channels? How about in-built PHP socket function? Ideally I would like to stick to PHP solution in order not to deal with translations and in-between REST APIs.

After researching this for days and going through solutions like RabbitMQ, Redis, Kafka, RatchetPHP, ZeroMQ, socket.io, RPC, SSE and etc I am completely lost. I need some guidance on which way to go.

Comment: Is your PHP Backend runing in Linux ?

Comment: Yes, it's linux - dockerized. I am also looking into crossbar.io

Answer (score 0):

Among all possible solutions here is how I would do it:

Install a web socket server, preferably implemented in PHP, on you Linux system.

Your web clients register with the server and listen for messages like broadcast from the server.

Your ajax script registers also with the server and sends a broadcast to the server if all work is done.

The server passes the broadcast to all registered clients.
You could use my implementation of such a web socket server that comes with all the needed client
libraries for JavaScript as well as for PHP that implement broadcast and feedback.

See  https://github.com/napengam/phpWebSocketServer